# Как хранить продолжительность в Django

Tags: django, django-admin

Есть необходимость хранить время, за которое производится то или иное действие.

В [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DurationField) нашёл DurationField, но с этим полем есть 2 проблемы:

1. К нему нету виджета, как к `TimeField` или `DateTimeField`.
2. Продолжительность по умолчанию хранится в секундах. Очевидно, что не 
   всегда это удобно для конечного пользователя.

Просто умножать указанные цифры на 60, чтобы получить минуты - не всегда удобно, т.к. в каком-то случае нужно указывать количество часов, или дней.

Есть ли какие-то идеи, как можно использовать это поле правильно?

Comment: Сделайте свой виджет, чо :)

Comment: @andreymal, прежде чем делать свой, хочется наверняка убедиться, что никто не сделал это до меня.

Comment: В секундах это в смысле в `unixtime`? Если да, то зачем умножать, если есть стандартные средства преобразования времени

Comment: Вообще, поле смоделировано пайтоновским timedelta. 
Про преобразование времени - это я для примера. Проблема ни в том, как преобразовывать, а в том, как сделать филд юзерфрендли.

Comment: У Django очень широкие возможности кастомизации админки. Какого именно юзерфрендли вам бы хотелось от DurationField? Как вы это видите?

Comment: Я считаю, что удобным было бы вводить данные при помощи виджета, вроде как в TimeField, нежели использовать просто строку.